# missing symbols or unicode character?

Tags: fonts, elementary-os

Once I finished installing elementary OS, it's all good.

After I did some changes for language, and switched it back, some symbols(unicode character?) are missing from terminal

[image]

those are two of missing symbols  ‘╭─’ ‘╰─’

Comment: Are you in a UTF-8 locale? (Post the output of `locale`.) What font are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Your terminal is just using a font which doesn't have those glyphs. What you need to do is change the terminal or display manager settings to use a different font for fixed width text, and that should be it.

Comment: +1 A lot of variable width fonts don't implement these because they can't be used very effectively that way (although that actually looks like a monospace font to me, which is what you want in a terminal).  It may also be a very obscure character (rounded corners...) -- I don't think any font implements the entire unicode set.

Answer (score 0):

The picture shows the Unicode *replacement character*, which is displayed when attempting to show a byte that does not correspond to legal UTF-8 encoding.

The question hints at what happened:

> After I did some changes for language, and switched it back, some symbols(unicode character?) are missing from terminal

for instance, if OP switched the locale to a non-UTF-8 encoding but did not change the terminal settings to use that encoding.

If a terminal simply lacks the appropriate character, it typically displays a box or empty space.  It's not likely to show the *replacement character* for a legal (but absent from font) Unicode value.  If your terminal does that, you should report it as a bug.  Likewise, if it displays the replacement character when not configured for Unicode, that also is a bug.